# Cat suddenly being aggressive

Tags: cats, behavior

Two cats - both male, neutered and have access outside.

Older cat has recently been hissing, hitting and yowling at the younger cat. Younger cat is not aggressive or retaliatory and is pretty frightened of him now.

He’s been to the vets and they couldn’t find anything obviously wrong. We’ve tried him on painkillers and he’s still behaving aggressively.

This is absolutely not normal for him, they’ve been getting along great up until this point. Any advice on how to help him/ make him less aggressive would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Because suddenly changes in behavior most times hint to an health problem: did you see more than one vet? Sometimes a new pair of eyes see new things.

Comment: what is the age of your two cats,aggression in cats can be easy to trigger and all that is needed can be the other cat smelling wrong like after a vet visit or contact with an other cat.

Comment: Has the vet checked for urinary tract infection or stones and arthritis? Both conditions are quite common and cause chronic pain, which in turn causes aggression. Malnutrition like a deficit of certain vitamins can also be a cause. It would help if you could [edit] your question and add the vets notes to the question.